# Passing in dynamic parameter names to Origen::Parameters?

Tags: origen-sdk

After looking at the [Origen Parameters feature](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/), I was wondering if it is possible to dynamically pass variables as names within the parameter scope.  For example:

```
[:tprog, :terase].each do |p|
  define_params :default do |params|
    params.send(p, 20.uS)
  end
end
```

thx

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens if you do? What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Your example doesn't work as written though since the method you are trying to call to define the parameter is `tprog=` and not just `tprog`.

So this would work:

```
[:tprog, :terase].each do |p|
  define_params :default do |params|
    params.send("#{p}=", 20.us)
  end
end
```